# Can't find module 'discord.js' for Discord bot

Tags: javascript

Since I have a fair amount of free time on my hands I figured I'd set myself a project, so I decided to build a discord bot. I may in the future make it more complicated but at the moment I just want to get it working, this is my code thus far (minus my token):

[image: 1]

This code worked completely fine about an hour ago, then suddenly it didn’t. I started randomly getting this error (I should make clear that I made no changes in the code to cause this issue. It just worked one minute, and then didn't the next):

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe .\index.js
Process exited with code 1
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module ‘discord.js’
```

I have tried the following:

- Uninstalling discord.js, then reinstalling it.
- Checking to see if the ‘Discord’ should be capitalised or not.
- Changing the version on the ‘version’ of my package.json.
- Completely rewriting my code from scratch in a new file.
- Reducing the code to just that first line of code.
- Running Visual Studio Code in administrator mode.
- Tweaking the code such that I provided an exact file location instead of just ‘discord.js’.

None of these have worked. I am basically brand new to coding (hence the very simple code) and just fancied messing around with it, but I have genuinely no idea what caused my issue or how to fix it as I have checked everything I can think of.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post your code as text and not as image.

Comment: firstly, there is such a thing as scope, therefore after the `client.on('message',message=>{})` block, the if statements are completely invalid

Comment: try changing directory to the folder the file's in, then type `node index.js` without the whole `C:\Program...`

Comment: @TheBombSquad How exactly would I do this ? Like I said I'm very new to coding so I'm still struggling a bit to put theory into practice.

Comment: well I simply meant `cd path/to/file` then `node index.js`

Comment: @TheBombSquad No luck, any other ideas ? Is it possibly a problem with Visual Studio Code ?

Answer (score 0):

So in raw defiance to this useless community, I now have a working bot, although admittedly I just found a guide that worked (previous ones didn't, I still don't know why), then copied their code.
The guide can be found here:

https://www.digitaltrends.com/gaming/how-to-make-a-discord-bot/

Maybe installing 'discord.io' directly into the same folder as the code might have been the fix ? Although I'm not sure why that would be it if fiddling with the directory didn't work ?

Either way, I hope this helps anyone with the same issue !

-Ollie